# What is the difference between accessing a class method via -> and via ::?

Tags: php

What is the difference between accessing a class method via -> and via ::?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

Comment: this is clearly a dup. doens't deserve +1

Answer (score 6):

The `->` is for accessing properties and methods of instantiated objects. The `::` is to access static methods, constants or overridden methods.

For more information:

- [Scope Resolution Operator (::)](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php)

Answer (score 4):

`::` is used for accessing static methods or attributes, so you don't have to instantiate an object of the containing class.

`->` is used for accessing methods or attributes of instantiated objects.

Answer (score 2):

Using the `->` means your accessing methods based on an instance (it retains state of the object, such as private/public variables set).

The `::` is a static method, meaning it has no baring if the object has or has not been initialized, but these methods pertain to this object.

---

Picture the following:

```
class Mustang
{
  var $gallons = 12; // gallons

  public function getFuel()
  {
    return $this->gallons;
  }

  public static function getEngine()
  {
    return "V8";
  }
}

$mustang = new Mustang(); // creating an instance

echo $mustang->getFuel(); // retrieve the fuel (instance, _this_ mustang)

echo Mustang::getEngine(); // echo a stat about Mustangs in general (static)
```

If you had an instance of a "Mustang", each instance could (hypothetically) have a specific amount of fuel to it (this is instance based, and would be accessible using `->`).

If you wanted something that still pertains to the mustang, but has no baring on the specific instance itself, you would refer to a static method (in this case all mustangs have a V8 in this case, symbolic of `::`).

Answer (score 1):

What Francois said is correct. The `::` operator is called the [Scope Resolution Operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php).... and (believe it or not) known as *paamayim-nekudotayim*. It is used when accessing static, constant, and overridden members of a **class**. I stress class because it is not used on specific **objects**. You can think of the scope resolution operator as meta to the class itself; it acts on itself and its parents. (Think about it, class constants don't belong to any specific object so you wouldn't use `->`

Which brings us to what is `->`? It's used to operate of **objects** and not **classes**. When you create a specific object you can access it's properties and methods using this operator. For example:

```
$john = new User(); //create the object
$john->age = 10; //accessing an object property
$age = $john->getAge(); //accessing an object method
```